# Move item to a list without copying

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Given

```
std::list<std::vector<float>> foo;
std::vector<float> bar;
```

How should I move `bar` to the end of `foo` without copying data?

Is this ok?

```
foo.emplace_back(std::move(bar));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this ok?
>
> `foo.emplace_back(std::move(bar));`

Yes, because:

1. `std::move(bar)` casts `bar` to an *rvalue reference*.
2. [`std::list::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back) takes any number of [*forwarding references*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) and uses them to construct an element at the end.
3. [`std::vector::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) has an overload *(6)* that takes an *rvalue reference*, which moves the contents of the *rhs* vector without performing any copy.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the code in the Q is certainly OK. Even using `push_back` would be OK:

```
foo.push_back(std::move(bar));
```

Comment: Personally, I think `push_back` should be preferred in this case. I think it is clearer.

Answer (score 5):

> How should I move `bar` to the end of `foo` without copying data?

Using the move constructor of `std::vector`:

```
foo.push_back(std::move(bar));
```

> Is this ok?
>
> ```
> foo.emplace_back(std::move(bar));
> ```

That is OK as well.